# Why is minmax value equal to maxmin value in two-player game?

Tags: game-theory

> In two-player games, a player's minmax value is always equal to his maxmin value.

This proposition is from *Essentials of Game Theory*. The minmax value is $\min_{s_{-i}}\max_{s_{i}} u_{i}(s_i,s_{-i})$ while the maxmin value is $\max_{s_{i}}\min_{s_{-i}} u_{i}(s_i,s_{-i})$, I believe.

I only understand that $\max\min\le\max\min$ because we have $\min\le \max$ at first and then applying $\max$ and $\min$ on both sides respectively changes nothing. But I really don't know why they are equal in two-player game as mentioned in the book.

(I know that this is true in zero-sum game for von Neumann's theorem. Maybe that proposition is a typo of the book?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that I am stupid. When considering one player, say $u_1$, we never care about $u_2$, so we can simply set $u_2$ to be $-u_1$ making it a zero-sum game. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. That was basically my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you consider only Player's $i$ payoff, it is as if they play a zero-sum game with only these payoffs. Player $i$ tried to maximize it, the other player to minimize it and indeed, the minimax=maximin (in mixed actions only. See  @Herr K.'s counterexample when only considering pure).

Answer (score 0):

The statement appears to be wrong. For a counterexample, consider player 1's (row player's) payoffs in the following two-player game:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
&C&D\\\hline
A&2,\;\cdot&1,\;\cdot\\\hline
B&0,\;\cdot&3,\;\cdot\\\hline
\end{array}
It can be verified that
\begin{equation}
\min_{s_2}\max_{s_1}u_1(s_1,s_2)=u_1(A,C)=2
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\max_{s_1}\min_{s_2}u_1(s_1,s_2)=u_1(A,D)=1.
\end{equation}
The two values are not equal.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. But it seems that $\min_{s_2}\max_{s_1}u_1(s_1,s_2)=u_1(A,D)=1 $ because player 1 will always play $A$ and the payoff of player 1 can be minimized by player 2 playing $D$. So minmax and maxmin are equal. Am I right?

Comment: @Wheel: Player 1's minmax value is the minimum of his best-case payoff. If player 2 chooses $C$, player 1's max payoff is $2$, for $D$, the max payoff is $3$. So *min*-ing the *max* payoffs, player 2 would choose $C$, resulting in the outcome $(A,C)$. Note that in minmax, "min" comes first and "max" comes after, as if it were a sequential game where player 2 moves first.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you! I made a mistake. It is really a counterexample of pure strategies. So I believe that proposition is correct only for mixed strategies.