# Why maxmin is equal to minmax in zero-sum games allowing for mixed strategies?

Tags: game-theory

Allowing for mixed strategies, maxmix payoff is equal to minmax payoff in zero-sum games. How to prove this one?

I can easily check that minmax payoff is always larger than or equal to maxmin payoff even without using mixed strategies, but it is hard to prove the reverse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is minmax value equal to maxmin value in two-player game?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3780871/why-is-minmax-value-equal-to-maxmin-value-in-two-player-game)

Comment: @JeanMarie I checked the post, but it didn’t.. can you elaborate on that?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I don’t understand how mixed strategies are used to prove this one.